# If and else statement technical term question

Tags: java, semantics

An `if` statement alone is considered "an `if` statement".

An `else` or `else if` statement alone is considered a "statement".

If I have a block of code that uses `if` and `else if` and `else` statement(s) together would that block of code be considered "a statement" or "statements"?

Which technical term is used?

Answer (score 1):

From a purely linguistic perspective, `if`, `else-if`, and similar structures are referred to as a "[Conditional Statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming))". This would cover each of the cases regardless. A singular `if` is a "Conditional", and an `if-elseif-else` is a "Conditional" as well.

There are special sub-categories of this, like ternary logic, but they all fall under the category of "Conditional Statements". So one tree is a conditional statement, and a group of logic trees is a set of conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to be found in the [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9).

The 'if-then-else statement' is defined in 14.9.2.

I see no evidence of an 'else statement' though.

Note that statements can contain statements: the 'if-statement' contains a statement after the 'expression' that is the if-condition.